# Injecting a JavaScript script using Selenium Driver + PhantomJS and handling the redirection correctly in Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, phantomjs

**My problem is:**

I have being developing a Python script that connects to an URL, and using the selenium driver I manage to inject a Javascript file, after this file executes the currently page is redirected. This's all done using selenium to handle Firefox:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox();
```

, but when I try to use PhantomJS as the browser, since it doesn't have any graphical interface:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS();
```

I can't handle the response properly. Still haven't found out if the driver is not injecting the script correctly or if it's an response handling problem. If someone has any ideas it'll be great to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on another question, but I think this will help:

After dealing with this same dilemma myself, I can wholeheartedly recommend using your preferred Selenium webkit (mine is Chrome) in conjunction with [XVFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).

XVFB allows you to heedlessly run a browser like Firefox, Chrome, etc. which basically eradicates all of the bugginess that inherently comes with using PhantomJS. While it’s definitely an awesome piece, it’s inner workings tend to have different interactions at times (I ran into issues for instance with not being able to TAB from one element to another like one can in any browser). If you are using Jenkins, there is an incredibly awesome Plugin which literally takes one click of a button. Otherwise, I’d definitely recommend checking [this](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747) out.

Phantom is a real pain in the ass, so it's definitely worth circumventing it :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was hoping to find something cross-platform. Is there a similar to xvfb?

Comment: Hmm not that I know of... XVFB is what I had my most success with, so I haven't tried any other options. There are other testing platforms like Mocha and Karma that you could check out, but they both unfortunately use Phantom if I'm not mistaken....

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Since I'm not expecting anymore answes I'll accept yours.

Comment: What operating system did you want to run on?